# are startService() Intents serialized?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

a) if my code calls `startService()` twice, will the Intents be processeced in the order I called them, or might they get switched randomly?

b) will the first run through `onStartCommand()` complete before the second call starts, or might they run in parallel?

I have read the [android services guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) and the reference.  While they clearly show how the `IntentService` worker threads are serialized, I've found little information on how the Intents are delivered and processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if my code calls startService() twice, will the Intents be processeced in the order I called them, or might they get switched randomly?

The behavior for `Service` in this regard is undocumented, last I checked. However, they should be called in the order they were issued, based on what seems to happen in practice.

> will the first run through onStartCommand() complete before the second call starts, or might they run in parallel?

That is up to you. By default, `onStartCommand()` on a `Service` is called on the main application thread, and therefore only one command is processed at a time. If you choose to fork threads from `onStartCommand()` to process commands, those threads may run in parallel.

> While they clearly show how the IntentService worker threads are serialized, I've found little information on how the Intents are delivered and processed.

`IntentService` maintains its own thread. You implement `onHandleIntent()` instead of (or possibly in addition to) `onStartCommand()`. Since there is only one thread, only one `onHandleIntent()` will be executed at a time.

Comment: thx for feedback - scratching more at B) if I **don't** start a thread in `onStartCommand()`, then the first run should complete before 2nd starts - yes?

Comment: @donfede: Yes. As I noted, `onStartCommand()` is called on the main application thread, and one thread cannot do two things at a time.

Comment: @donfede: Glad to hear it!